# style multiple elements at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

i created four drop down select lists in html and dynamically load them from an ajax object. i made it so you could select an item in the select list and an onchange event that ran a javascript function that would get the items respective data and display in a table underneath the select list. there are four of these on the page and so that a person could select four different items and then compare their characteristics.  THat all works like a charm, however im using a :hover in css to try and highlight the characteristics of the four products that match the one being hovered upon ie: if you hover over one product name it highlights all the product names. heres the code

```
function displayStrainInfo(event){
    var eventTrigger = event.currentTarget;
    Inspection::Ptr inspectionModelvar testOption =    document.getElementById(eventTrigger.id);
    var selectedIndex = testOption.options[testOption.selectedIndex].index;
    //alert(flowerPeriod[0].firstChild.data);
    //alert(eventTrigger.id.substr(6,5));
    document.getElementById(eventTrigger.id.substr(6,5)).innerHTML = "<table class='strainInfoTable'><tr class='infoRow'><td id='strain_Name'>Strain Name: " + products[selectedIndex - 1].firstChild.data + "</td><td>Strain Genetics: " + genetics[selectedIndex - 1].firstChild.data + "</td></tr><tr><td class='infoRow' colspan='2'>Indica:" + raceIndica[selectedIndex - 1].firstChild.data + "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspSativa: " + raceSativa[selectedIndex - 1].firstChild.data + "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspRuderalis: " + raceRuderalis[selectedIndex - 1].firstChild.data + "</td></tr><tr><td class='infoRow'>Height: " + height[selectedIndex - 1].firstChild.data + "</td></tr><tr><td class='infoRow'>Flower Period: " + flowerPeriod[selectedIndex - 1].firstChild.data + "</td></tr><tr><td class='infoRow' id='botom'>Potency: " + potency[selectedIndex - 1].firstChild.data + "</td></tr></table>";
}
```

the above code is the function that creates the table that displays the choosen products information.

```
#strain_Name:hover{
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

above here is the hover css for testing the effect on the name element.

it highlights just fine but it only highlights the element hovered over even though all the tables have the same .class and #id to match. just a newbie so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...even though all the tables have the same .class and #id to match

It sounds like you have duplicate IDs. IDs must be unique.

You can use the class attribute and define a class selector in CSS to match multiple elements and/or use a more [elaborate CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).

**Simple Example of Using a Class Selector**

```
<div class="foo">1</div>
<div class="foo">2</div>
<div class="foo">3</div>
<div class="foo">4</div>

.foo:hover { background-color: red; }
```

**Example of Using jQuery + Class Selectors**

Full working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mSWcw/

```
$(".parent").hover(
    // fired on entry
    function(){
        var matchingChildren = $(".foo", this); // select all children with the class "foo" within the parent object
        matchingChildren.addClass("hovered");
    },

    // fired on exit
    function(){
        var matchingChildren = $(".foo", this);
        matchingChildren.removeClass("hovered");
    }  
);​
```

Comment: like   <td class='infoRow'></td> and then .infoRow:hover{color:red;} ive tried that as well but only styled the one being hovered. no same ids

Comment: go to burytheseed.com/wtpn and click on the vs tab (sorry still havnt coding for dif resolutions) there should be four drop downs. pick something in two and then hover over the strain name and see what happens

Comment: @Beanno1116 - I went to your page but I just get an alert box when I hover on an item. Regardless, are you trying to style a set of elements when you hover on just one of them? The easiest way to do that may be with a little bit of script.

Comment: exactly long story short i want to style a set of elements by hoverig over one. i have tried a mouseover event to change the class names to the style needed, however it only styles the one. i have tried many different ways to avail and am going crazy.  lol

Comment: here is the function im using                                                                                 function highlightHovered(data){
                        if (data == 'name'){
                        //alert(data);
                        document.getElementById('strainName').className = "hovered";
                        }

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery instead of raw JavaScript? it makes things like this **much** easier. On mouseover, you could use a jQuery selector to grab the elements you wanted and apply the styles you want.

Comment: thats what im thinking of doing.  being that i cannot have more then one id of the same value is there a way to use jquery to select by element name?

Comment: cause i can get it to style one but i cant get it to style multiple elements. would i have to loop through the array returned from like a getElementsByName function to change the style dynamically??

Comment: Sorry for the delay...check my updated answer for a working sample that I think will put you on the right track.